# Make a menu inline horizontal

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out a way how to make the "Webshop" submenu horizontal instead of vertical.

I can see that this is the class I should change some CSS on. But I really do not know where to start:

`menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-1731`

Can somebody get me started on this one?

Comment: Here Try that `#menu-item-1731 > ul {display:flex; right:0; width:auto ; padding:0; } #menu-item-1731 > ul > li{padding:0; } #menu-item-1731 > ul > li:first-child{display:none; }`

Comment: Thanks for this Zohir, that worked. When I hover over the sub-menues the menu is haning over the main menu. Is there a way to correct this? I updated the page with your code.

Comment: You need these `#menu-item-1731>ul>li>ul.sub-menu {top:100%; left:0; }`

Comment: Thank you a lot - you dont want to lay answer?

Comment: I don't see How an answer would be helpful to future readers since the problem is specific to your website

Comment: Ok I just have to leave it open then. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#menu-item-1731>ul {
    display: flex;
    right: 0;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

You could alternatively use flex-direction to column. Since you are using flex container

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it did not make any difference. But the code @Zohir made is working.

But the submenu are hangig over the main menu when you hover over. Maybe you have a suggestion how to solve this?